# How to make grid column width the smaller of two values?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make the column width of a 3-column grid to be the minimum of `1fr` or `100px`.
Here's what I tried, but dev tools say it's not a valid value.

```
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, min(100px, 1fr)));
}
```

Why isn't this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use percentage and not `1fr`

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* (100% - (N-1)*Gap)/N */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min(100px, calc(100% - 2*5px)/3));
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.my-grid > div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey in the minmax you don't need to pass the min(), in minmax the first parameter is the min value and second is max value, you can set it accordingly.

like minmax(1fr,33%)

Comment: But would this still be responsive? Because on small screen sizes, `1fr` would be less than 100px. Basically, I need the column width to be `1fr` on small screens and `100px` on large monitors.

Comment: In that case, you have to use the auto-fit keyword. You can read about the auto-sizing columns here: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/           

And I am sharing with you the link to my codepen, with the example

LInk : https://codepen.io/Shbham07/pen/xxzemJM